# Providing sync and async methods

Tags: .net, asynchronous, async-await

With any new library project, I am torn between providing `async` methods, normal synchronized methods, or both. In this example, I'm attempting to provide both a sync and an async method to produce the same overall result. [Because I'm as lazy as possible](https://quoteinvestigator.com/2014/02/26/lazy-job/), I'd like to simply wrap or unwrap whatever the other method does.

There are plenty of questions to do with calling async from sync and the various difficulties of unwrapping exceptions and returning to the correct execution context, but I cannot find any questions around how to allow consuming developers choose between an async or sync execution path.

Let's take a look at two potential development patterns I could use to provide both a sync and an async method of the same work.

```
public interface IMyService
{
    MyResponse DoWork(MyRequest req);
    Task<MyResponse> DoWorkAsync(MyRequest req, CancellationToken token);
}

public class MyServiceSyncWrapped : IMyService
{
    public MyResponse DoWork(MyRequest req)
    {
        //Do the actual work, but sync-d
    }

    //No need to make this async/await, here it's pure overhead
    public Task<MyResponse> DoWorkAsync(MyRequest req, CancellationToken token)
    {
        //Return DoWork wrapped in a task
    }
}

public class MyServiceAsyncWrapped : IMyService
{
    public MyResponse DoWork(MyRequest req)
    {
        //Return DoWorkAsync, unwrapped!
    }

    //async/await actually potentially adds value here
    public async Task<MyResponse> DoWorkAsync(MyRequest req, CancellationToken token)
    {
        //Do the actual work, fully async-ly
    }
}
```

Is there any significant value in providing both sync and async methods (or is this an anti-pattern)? 
If it is deemed desirable, and keeping in mind how tricky unwrapping async'd code is vs how much better practice it is to allow async to fully traverse the codebase, what drives value for each approach (or is one clearly preferable)?
Should I just ditch sync methods and force other developers to develop for async?

Comment: "Because I'm as lazy as possible, I'd like to simply wrap or unwrap whatever the other method does." This is the most important sentence in the question, because it indicates that you have a very wrong idea about how asynchronous workflows differ from synchronous workflows. You can't build a synchronous workflow out of an asynchronous workflow by simply blocking; that will introduce deadlocks. You can't build an asynchronous workflow out of a synchronous workflow by moving work to worker threads; that wastes expensive resources.

Comment: What you need to to is stop, take a step back, and **ask your clients what their needs are when dealing with high-latency operations**. Implementation strategy choices should be driven by the needs of the clients, not by your laziness or eagerness!

Comment: Asking the client what implementation suits them best and implementing that correctly is clearly the most lazy option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pattern that Microsoft uses is that the synchronous versions of their methods are completely different implementations than their asynchronous versions. The synchronous versions are not just wrappers around the asynchronous versions.

You can see this in their source code. For example, compare [`File.InternalReadAllText()`](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.IO.FileSystem/src/System/IO/File.cs#L290) (which is used by [`File.ReadAllText()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalltext?view=netcore-3.0)) with [`File.InternalReadAllTextAsync()`](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.IO.FileSystem/src/System/IO/File.cs#L699) (which is used by [`File.ReadAllTextAsync()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalltextasync?view=netcore-3.0)).

In fact, there are dangers in synchronously waiting on asynchronous methods, as explained in this article: [Don't Block on Async Code](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html). There are ways to avoid that, of course, as long as you're aware that it's happening.

My personal philosophy has been to not create synchronous methods that just wrap an asynchronous method. If the caller feels they need to do it, let them do it.

Comment: Somehow I hadn't noticed that there are async and sync versions of things microsoft make (in .net for example there's the whole parallel library). But your answer does raise the correct and interesting point; sync and async _ARE_ different methods.

Answer (score 1):

It is only meaningful to write an async version of a procedure if the sync version has an idle wait in it, usually a wait for another process to finish, like waiting for a file to open, or the results of a database query, or some information of the internet.

A sync method would just wait idly for the other process to finish, thus locking execution of your program. In an async-await method the thread would look around to see if it can do something else instead of idly waiting.

This can be most easily understood if you compare this with a cook making breakfast, as described in [this interview with Eric Lippert](https://www.i-programmer.info/professional-programmer/i-programmer/7154-c-guru-an-interview-with-eric-lippert.html?start=1). Search somewhere in the middle for async await.

If a cook has to make breakfast synchronously, he will start boiling water, wait until the water boils, use the boiling water to make tea, start toasting bread, wait until the bread is toasted, start boiling the eggs, wait until the eggs are boiled, etc. You'll see all the idle waits.

An async-await cook would start boiling water, but instead of waiting for the water to boil, he would start toasting bread and boiling water. While he has to wait for these processes to finish, he is free to do something else instead, for instance slice tomatoes. After a while the water for the tea is boiling. He makes tea and continues working until the bread is toasted, etc. As long as there is work to do, the cook won't wait idly, but do things he can do without the results of the tasks he started.

**Back to your question**

If a procedure doesn't have to wait for some other process to finish, it is not meaningful to create an async version for it. If the procedure takes some considerable amount of time, let your caller decide whether he needs to be responsive and start a task that calls your function.

Another reason would be to implement an interface. This might be a reason not to create one interface that has both the sync and async versions, but two interfaces: one with the sync functions and one with the async functions. Classes with functions that don't have to wait idly will only implement the sync version of the interface.

If you have a class with two methods that have the same functionality, the only difference is that one is async, and the other not, consider to break the method into submethods and only create async versions when you can call an async function:

```
IEnumerable<int> ReadNumbers(string fileName1)
{
    // Read File 1, wait idly,
    string text1 = ReadTextFile(fileName1);

    // convert the read texts to numbers, and return in ascending order
    IEnumerable<int> result = ConvertToAscendingInt(text1);
    return result;
}
```

This method waits idly while reading the text file. To prevent this, call the async version of it. All other things are non idly, no need for an async version:

```
async Task<IEnumerable<int>> ReadNumbersAsync(string fileName1)
{
    // Start reading File 1 async
    string text1 = await ReadTextFileAsync(fileName1);

    // convert the read texts to numbers, and return in ascending order
    IEnumerable<int> result = ConvertToAscendingInt(text1);
    return result;
}
```

This way, most code will be in the submethods. It is easier to see that the sync and async methods do the same thing. If in future the conversion is done differently it will automatically be done for both the sync and the async version.

Finally, you could decide to let the sync version call the async version. The task overhead will slow down the sync version:

```
IEnumerable<int> ReadNumbers(string fileName1)
{
   var taskReadNumbers = Task.Run( () => ReadNumbersAsync(fileName1);
   taskReadNumbers.Wait();
   return taskReadNumbers.Result();
}
```

For simplicity I left out exception handling

Comment: _For simplicity I left out exception handling_ is exactly what I'm worried about when wrapping actually useful async with a dangerous sync, or making async a useless throwaway stump. The concept of "X method should be sync" and "Y method should be async" is perhaps the way to go, as also explicitly pointed out by Gabriel.

Comment: Perhaps the conclusion I could draw would be, were I to create a kettle API to produce boiled water from a kettle and tap water, clearly I would make that an `async` method to promote a more parallel, less blocked, consuming work processes... but methods to interact with the kettle, except waiting for the boiling, should probably be sync.